# Support to share button in amp-html

Tags: amp-html, share-button

Does AMP have support to facebook, twiiter and google plus share buttons? There's no clear information about this issue here or on github.

Comment: refer - https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-social-share.html

Comment: As you'll see in the reference above, the Facebook button (<amp-social-share type="facebook">) won't work without the app_id. Without it you get an error from Facebook, "Invalid App ID: 0". Other buttons (e.g. twitter, pinterest) work without extra code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been proposed but not implemented yet: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1201

In meantime you can just create standard HTML links for these - which are **much** quicker to load than the bloated JavaScript official versions (though without interactive stuff like counters). For example see this page: https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/06/18/basic-performant-sharing-buttons/